# How to explicitly access the Connector from Widget Side into Vaadin 7?

Tags: vaadin

I create a Widget with his Server Side Class and the Client Side (Connector Class, ServerRPC Class, State Class and Widget Class).

**Connector :**

```
@Connect(Custom.class)
public class CustomConnector extends ButtonConnector {

   ...
   public void myFunc() {
      // DO Something
   }
}
```

**Widget :**

```
public class CustomWidget extends VButton {
  ...
  private CustomConnector conn = new CustomConnector();
  public CustomWidget () {
    conn.myFunc();
  }
  ...
}
```

Now from the Widget Class i want to explicitly call/access the Connector Object, which are not a Singleton, so that i can access a function too. How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should not access connector directly from GWT widget. It is against Vaadin 7  architecture where GWT widgets are objects independent from vaadin at all.

However if we are talking about dirty migration from Vaadin 6 to 7 solution could be:

`ComponentConnector connector = ConnectorMap.get(client).getConnector(CustomWidget.this); // client is taken from updateFromUIDL method (Vaadin6)`

Better solution will be to add "state" listener to the widget

```
public interface CustomWidgetStateListener {
     public void stateChanged();
}

public class CustomWidget extends VButton {
  ...
     CustomWidgetStateListener listener;
     public void addStateListener(CustomWidgetStateListener listener) {
          this.listener = listener;
     }
     public void notifyStateChanged() { // You can call notifyStateChanged() whenever you want to notify connector
           listener.stateChanged();
     }

   ...
 }
 public class CustomConnector extends ButtonConnector {

 public CustomConnector() {
     getWidget().addStateListener(new CustomWidgetStateListener() {
           public void stateChanged() {
              myFunc();
           }
      });
   }

 ...
 public void myFunc() {
  // DO Something
 }
 }
```